# WP event manager widget only show if there is some events

Tags: wordpress

i want to show event title if there is some events, if no event is there i dont want to show event title. how can i solve this problem, please help me. iam using Event Manager plugin.sorry for my bad english 
[image: ie only show this widget if there is some events.]

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Inside your WP site there is the following path: \site.com\wp-content\themes\theme_name\functions.php

*In case of not having this file you created.

Step 2 : Please insert into file functions.php the following code:

```
<?php
function em_mod_custom_events_list(){
        $events = EM_Events::get(array('scope'=>'future','limit'=>10));
        ?>
        <table>
                <tbody>
        <?php
        $start = false;
        $limit = 3;
        $count = 1;
        foreach( $events as $EM_Event ){
                if ( !empty($EM_Event->event_name) ){
                        ?>
                        <?php if ( !$start ) { ?>
                        <tr>
                        <?php $start = true; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                                <td><?php echo $EM_Event->output("#_EVENTLINK"); ?></td>
                        <?php
                                if ( $count == $limit ){
                                        ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                        $start = false;
                                        $count = 1;
                                }else{
                                        $count++;
                                }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                }
        }
        ?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php

}
```

Step 3 : Save file and Test

1) Using templates --> http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/using-template-files

2) Create your own page event --> http://wp-events-plugin.com/tutorials/create-custom-event-information-pages/

The documentation is quite clear and you can help.

Comment: thank for your replay, bt if there is no events, i dont want to  show the wodget.

Comment: Perhaps, You can make an "if" validating when is less than 0 ( or  <?php $start = true; ?> http://pastebin.com/mcaE69Ja Paste in your theme functions.php

Comment: Dear pio i solve this problem in another way, your support helped me to a very large extend. thanks

Comment: Nice Shijinmon, please share your answer, grettings from Colombia